# how to insert using timestamp oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I made a 'Kereta' table:

```
CREATE TABLE Kereta (
  ID_Kereta         NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT kr_id_kr_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  Nama_Kereta       VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT kr_nama_kr_nn NOT NULL,
  Jam_Keberangkatan TIMESTAMP    CONSTRAINT kr_jk_nn NOT NULL,
  Jam_Tiba          TIMESTAMP    CONSTRAINT kr_jt_nn NOT NULL,
  Stasiun_Asal      VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT kr_sa_nn NOT NULL,
  Stasiun_Tujuan    VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT kr_st_nn NOT NULL
)
```

Then i tried to insert `13.00` to `Jam_Keberangkatan` field. I can't insert one by one because of `NOT NULL` constraint, what should i do?

Comment: `'13.00'` is not a valid value for a `TIMESTAMP` column.

Comment: There is no datatype for only time in Oracle. The datatype TIMESTAMP always includes both date and time.If your time value is actually an interval you could use datatype INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. Another option would be to store as a TIMESTAMP using the same date all the time and only varying the time part. You could use a check constraint to make sure you always use the same date part.

Comment: Why are you going to insert timestamp only if you put constraints that force you to fill all fields?